# Change font type and size programmatically on the console

Tags: powershell, terminal, fonts, console, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Of course I can go into settings and change fonts and that question has been answered with many great answers elsewhere. This is quite a different question (or at least, I have not found an answer yet). There is a small [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38079524/change-the-powershell-console-font-programmatically) on this (just for PowerShell though) 4 years and 7 months ago, but that seemed to be a dead end (and was before the existence of WSL and Windows Terminal of course).

If I am in a console I would like to be able to type a command to change the font of the console that I'm in (whether by registry or json settings in Windows Terminal etc)?

e.g. `Resize-Console Consolas 14` inside the console would immediately change the console to that font size, without having to go into the settings panel etc.

I would be very happy if a solution only worked on Windows Terminal, as that is clearly the one-size-fits-all future that Microsoft are focusing on for consoles on Windows, and it has a json settings structure that is probably more easily modified than other consoles.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre It seems that the original question with 7k views is marked as a duplicate still...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the font settings are only available through the `settings.json` at the moment.  Usually I'd recommend using `jq` to edit the json, but `settings.json` includes comments, which make it "not really json" according to `jq`.

(Aside - This isn't really a `jq` issue.  Mixing code (comments) inside a data structure does make it tough to process.  I think you'd really have to shift from processing the data structure to processing the AST.  In my experience, most libraries won't/can't retain comments inside of data, no matter what the data type.)

If you are okay stripping out the comments (I'm not - They are very useful), then you could do this with a fairly straightforward simple jq query/set.

But if we want to leave the comments in, we need to treat the `settings.json` as simply "text", and go old-school with something like `sed`.  Note that this example assumes that you have added `"fontFace"` and `"fontSize" inside your` profiles.defaults`.  If you have or want it set on a per-profile basis, you'll need to adjust the regex accordingly.

Here's my section, abbreviated:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://aka.ms/terminal-profiles-schema",

...

    // A profile specifies a command to execute paired with information about how it should look and feel.
    // Each one of them will appear in the 'New Tab' dropdown,
    //   and can be invoked from the commandline with `wt.exe -p xxx`
    // To learn more about profiles, visit https://aka.ms/terminal-profile-settings
    "profiles":
    {
        "defaults":
        {
            // Put settings here that you want to apply to all profiles.

            // From Nerd Fonts
            // https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts
            "fontFace": "CaskaydiaCove NF",
            //"fontFace": "CodeNewRoman NF",
            //"fontFace": "SauceCodePro NF",
            //"fontFace": "UbuntuMono NF",
            //"fontFace": "Consolas",
            "fontSize": 13,
            "cursorShape": "filledBox"
        },
...
```

With that in mind, the following `sed` invocations work for me to change the fontFace and fontSize:

```
winhome=$(powershell.exe -c 'Write-Host -NoNewLine  $env:userprofile' | xargs -0 wslpath)
cd ${winhome}/AppData/Local/Packages/Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe/LocalState
sed -i '/"defaults"/,/fontFace/s/^\(.*fontFace": \).*/\1"Consolas",/' settings.json
sed -i '/"defaults"/,/fontSize/s/\([^/]*fontSize": \)[0-9]*/\115/' settings.json
```

The first two lines aren't strictly necessary if you wanted to hardcode to your user path, of course.

A couple of other caveats for these `sed` scripts:

- The "real" fontFace line must be the *first* uncommented one.  This script will change the first one it comes across, regardless of whether it is commented or not.  Same with fontSize, of course.
- Adjust the script to not add a comma needed.

---

Comment: This is really great, I'll be able to setup a function using `sed` inside my `.bashrc` for when using WSL, and a PowerShell script. to do something equivalent for when working in PowerShell. Thanks.